# How can I filter out particular MAC addresses when running tshark on a pcap trace?

Tags: wireshark, packet-analysis, tcpdump, pcap

I've tried a number of things, but none of them seem to do the trick. I want to run this command:

```
tshark -r data.pcap -T fields -e frame.time_epoch -e frame.len
```

but to have it ignore any packets from/to one or more devices that have a specific MAC address. I've tried variants of `not eth.addr==`, `mac !=`, etc with the `-Y` flag.

If this is not possible with tshark, a separate command (e.g. tcpdump) to preprocess the pcap and filter packets out into a new file would work too. Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `not ether host 01:23:45:67:89:ab`. To filter only source or destination address use `not ether src` or `not ether dst`.

Check http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html

Comment: Thanks, that's only tcpdump, right?

Comment: It's for pcap, works in Wireshark, so it should work in tshark, too.